# Formatting a web page for printing

Tags: css, printing

My company has developed a SaaS solution for allowing users to create forms for data collection and after submission allows the end users to print their form submissions. Forms have no standard width or height as each form creator will have different requirements. We are running into the obvious problems of the content running off the page due to width being 1000px and page junk like footers, urls, and header items from the browser.

Beyond the printer friendly CSS template is there any other options someone can recommend to transform the page like Word/Excel to print within a printable area and remove browser items? Are there any known PDF options that can do something similar? The best option would probably be to have the web page converted/fitted to a PDF and allow end user to download or print.

If CSS is the only option, any templates that would be recommended?

Comment: This question has been asked a bizillion times. Did you look at any of the existing answers? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=print+stylesheet

Comment: I see questions about specific elements and printing, not an entire page and conversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use a jquery plugin long time ago the name is [PrintElement](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/), with this plugin you can print whatever all the information contained inside an element in the DOM.

so my best bet here will be to format the HTML and target to that specific tag inside your page, in the case you mentioned earlier it could be the scenario when you have a header, the content and a footer, so use the printEment plugin and target to the content object, it could be a div for example.

```
<header></header>
<div class="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

so you can use the plugin as follows:

```
$('Selector').printElement();
```

and on top of that if you add the media css files the you'll have a nice strategy for print.